# How do I set a background color for each item in a list view based on content

Tags: android

So I've been modifying the notepad tutorial code: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html .

Basically what I want to do is to create specific layout styles (i.e. background color) for different rows within the ListView based on the content. So for example, the text for the title is "1" so the background of that row will be red.  Or, if the text for the title is "2" then the background of that row (or list item) will be green.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a summary of the the rows in the database and color-code each row based upon what category (numerical field) the item is stored as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use SimpleCursorAdapter, and you need to write your own in order to change the output. In your adapter, which handles the presentation of your data, you can override the method getView(). Then populate each row with the data from the db. And depending on the data, set a different background color.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v ==  null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
    }
    Cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.bg);

    if (Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex("column")).equals("black")) {
        img.setImageBackground(Color.Black);
    }

    return v;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this, would you happen to have more sample code or a tutorial that is similar to this? I'm very very new to Android development so any examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You have probably solved your adapter issue by now. I'll pass a link to a useful document http://www.slideshare.net/peterbuck/getting-fancy-with-lists. FYI, Just noticed they have deprecated one of the SimpleCursorAdapter's constructors.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just now getting to this, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Hwa Rang's answer is correct. You might also want to use the getItem method to get the item at a particular position on the list to determine what type of data it is. Then change the background color of that row in getView method